double free or corruption (out), coredump. Where can I find the coredump?
I have been working in Fedora on a C++ client for the BaseX XML database. The original version of the client was developed in Eclipse and consisted of a test program and some source files that allowed communication with the database. The Eclipse version of the code gives no error messages when executed.
For the next version of the program, I used the files used for communication to develop a shared library. All I had to do for this was to add a public header.
The shared library can now be installed locally.
The command LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib/lib64 ./libTest gives the same result as the original version but ends up with
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)

Valgrind cannot be used to inspect a library. And I also get no message about the location of the coredump.
How can I fix memory problems in a library?

Valgrind will work on any code that executes.

Have you tried
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib/lib64 valgrind ./libTest

?
Preferably with the libraries in ~/lib/lib64 built with debuginfo.
Memcheck should detect and report the double free.
If you really need a core dump, that is controlled by 'resource limits'. You can change it from your shell using either limit or ulimit (depending on which shell you use). You can then load the core file with lldb or gdb.
